# Blazor Webassembly appsettings and environment variables not loading in staging enviroment

Tags: docker, environment-variables, blazor, blazor-webassembly, appsettings

When I run my Blazor webassembly project in the development environment the `appsettings.Development.json` is loaded into the `WebAssemblyHostConfiguration` instance.

`WebAssemblyHostConfiguration` example:

```
builder.Configuration["key"];
```

But when I set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable to `Staging` on my Linux host, my Blazor webassembly project does not load the `appsettings.Staging.json` into the `WebAssemblyHostConfiguration` instance. All variables return empty.

What do I have to do to tell Blazor to use my `appsettings.Staging.json`? My staging environment is running in a Linux docker container and my development environment is running in IIS Express

***Update***

Despite me settings the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to Staging when I run my Blazor Webassembly project in a docker container the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set to Production. I have no idea why it's being set to Production when I clearly set all my environment variables inside my docker compose

Comment: How do you set your ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable? Is it possible your setting it as a user variable instead of system variable

Comment: @Vee I am setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable via my docker-compose file: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment

Comment: Does `docker exec container env` return ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT with the correct value?